# How to get month and day from day count using java script?

Tags: javascript

if day count is 31, then **month is 1** and **day is 31**.

if day count is 38, then month is 2 and day is 7.

if year is long year total days of year is 366 and if its not total days of year is 365.

so. Assume the year is not long year(365 days). So if i take day count is 334. the month is should be 11 (November) and day should be 30, But i can't get is . i followed following way.

```
function test(days){
var day;
var month;
if(days<=31){
    month=1;
    day=days;
}
else if(days<=59){
    month=2;
    day=days-31;
}
else if(days<=90){
    month=3;
    day=days-59;
}
else if(days<=120){
    month=4;
    day=days-90;
}
else if(days<=151){
    month=5;
    day=days-120;
}
else if(days<=181){
    month=6;
    day=days-151;
}
else if(days<=212){
    month=7;
    day=days-181;
}
else if(days<=243){
    month=8;
    day=days-212;
}
else if(days<=273){
    month=9;
    day=days-243;
}
else if(days<=304){
    month=10;
    day=days-273;
}
else if(days<=334){
    month=11;
    day=days-304;
}
else if(days<=365){
    month=12;
    day=days-334;
}

    alert(month);
    alert(day);
```

}

Comment: Is this for a school project where you have to use primitive if-statements?  If not, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: do you mean that when days=334, you dont get month=11 and day=30? what are you getting then?

Comment: @itamecodes month is 11 and days=29;

Comment: please verify your value of days because i dont know of any computer which will give you 334-304=29 ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myDate=new Date();   //new date to get current year
myDate = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);    //set to 1st of January (this year)

var x = 334;   //the day shift needed

myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + (x - 1));   //add the days to the date object we already built

var month = (myDate.getMonth() + 1);   //get the month. Add 1 since it's zero based
var day = myDate.getDate();   //get the day of month

alert(month + ' ' + day);   //do what you need to
```

Added whole process explanation to the comments of my code. It's possible to simplify this a little but I wanted to make sure you'd understand the whole algorithm.

Basically you take the beginning of the year, add the days you need and ask your object what month and day is set to it at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Keep It Simple Stupid (KISS):

```
var year = 2013
var day_of_year = 1

var d = new Date(year, 0, day_of_year)

var day_of_month = d.getDate()
var month_of_year = d.getMonth() + 1

console.log(day_of_month)
console.log(month_of_year)
```

**ADDENDUM:**

In regards to your question in the comments (I may be over tired though, because I don't see that comment anymore), to get the days in a given year, you can do the following:

```
var baseYear = 1992

var baseDate = new Date(baseYear, 0);
var extendedDate = new Date(baseYear + 1, 0, 0);

var daysInYear = 1 + ((extendedDate - baseDate) / 86400000)

console.log(daysInYear)
```

Comment: Best answer.  Funny that JS doesn't have a dayOfYear function on Date.  Wait, no not funny, the built-in Date object is lame.  But it's nice to see that some things can still be done.

Comment: Yeah it's sort of ridiculous; but to be honest, I've yet to really find good built-in functionality for dates in any language (though lower level languages definitely have more room to build on). But yeah, JS is definitely at the bottom of the barrel :P. That momentjs library though looks really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the month using a lot less code (note, no bounds checking):

```
function getMonth(day) {
    var i = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    while(sum < day) {
        sum += days[i++];
    }
    return i;
}
```

Or even:

```
function getMonth(day) {
    var i = 0, 
        days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    for (var sum = 0; sum < day; sum += days[i++]);
    return i;
}
```

Include the day of the month:

```
function getMonthAndDay(day) {
    var i = 0, sum = 0;
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    while(sum < day) {
        sum += days[i++];
    }
    return [i, day - sum + days[i - 1]];
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  The OP can easily adjust for leap years.

Comment: Might want to finish it up and return not only the month but the day in the month too.  Return it as a [month, date] array.  Easy to do and  fun.

Comment: This won't help with the leap year. And you can't even tell what year this is because the function only takes one parameter. Also the result is month, not month and day.

Comment: Problem statement says to ignore leap years, but yeah, I'll go ahead and add the other part.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me .Test it here http://jsfiddle.net/PcZQ3/   . Just saw a typo in your code though . You have declared `function` as `funtion` .

Comment: it does nothing...you can delete it

Comment: but check with this daycount 329 ? 329 means month=11 and day =24 but answer not true ...

Comment: Please pick the solution suggested in either of the other answers.I dont recommend using your solution. i was just testing out your use case of 334 days..and according to your algo 329 will be 11th month and 25 days!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
function test(dayCount) {
    var isLeapyear = false;
    var daysByMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

    if (isLeapyear)
        daysByMonth = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

    var month = 1;
    var day = 1;

    var days = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {       
        if ( days + daysByMonth[i] > dayCount)
        {
            day = (dayCount - days);
            break;
        }
        days += daysByMonth[i];    
        month++;
    }

    console.log('month : ' + month + ' - day : ' + day);
}

test(38);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here looking to find the month and date from a year's day number, the best way is to use a preexisting library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com).

Here's an example using node. After first running `npm install moment`, you can just do this:

```
> var moment = require('moment')
> var d = moment().dayOfYear(334)
undefined
> d.format()
'2013-11-30T23:45:36-08:00'
> [d.month()+1, d.date()]
[ 11, 30 ]
```

The `+1` is because moment uses month numbers starting from 0.

The library takes care of daylight savings, time zones, leap years and similar things that you don't want to write in your own code, unless you are learning or practicing or having fun.

**ADDENDUM**

Sg'te'gmuj showed how to do this using plain JavaScript (no need for a third party library).  Here is that solution as a function:

```
> function monthAndDay(year, dayOfYear) {
    var date = new Date(year, 0, dayOfYear);
    return [date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate()]
  }
```

It's pretty sweet.  Here it is in action, both for a leap year and for a non leap year:

```
> monthAndDay(2013, 334)
11,30
> monthAndDay(2012, 334)
11,29
```